# Can we create a WordPress read-only virtual field derived from three other fields?

Tags: custom-field, pods-framework

Our app has three different dates representing three key dates for a Project (one of our PODS CPTs). One of the common calculations we make is deriving an overall "Status" of the project from those three dates (based on the emptiness of one or two of those dates). We want to avoid the clunky solution of making a forth non-date field in which we repeat which status the project is right now, which would require extra work from content editors and have considerable risk of falling out of sync with the true dates. Is there any way we could crystalize this "Status" calculation into a read-only field that we could reference with code or with our FacetWP plugin?

Comment: If you've made three fields already I don't understand why you can't just make a 4th field and set it to `disabled` ie. `<input type="date" id="status" value="put status here" disabled/>`  Same process as adding the other fields but if it's dynamically generated on page load, don't save it with the CPT.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.  Not familiar with FacetWP.

Comment: The fourth field needs to have a value that is a function of the other three: lF NOT A, then ... IF NOT B then.... and so on.